# Mysql inconsistent number of rows count(*) vs table.table_rows in information_schema

Tags: mysql, count, information-schema

i came across a strange phenomenon, and i hope, that someone can explain this to me:

i have a some "static" tables (they change once per day).

```
mysql> select 'appObjectGroups' as tbl, count(*) as num from appObjectGroups
  union select 'appObjectDependencies' as tbl, count(*) as num from appObjectDependencies
  union select 'appObjectUrls' as tbl, count(*) as num from appObjectUrls 
  union select 'appObjectValues' as tbl, count(*) as num from appObjectValues 
  union select 'appObjects;' as tbl, count(*) as num from appObjects;
+-------------------------+------+
| tbl                     | num  |
+-------------------------+------+
| appObjectGroups         | 1149 |
| appObjectDependencies   | 6885 |
| appObjectUrls           | 1162 |
| appObjectValues         | 3795 |
| appObjects;             | 5409 |
+-------------------------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select table_name as tbl, table_rows as num from information_schema.tables where table_schema='mySchema' and table_name like 'app%';
+-------------------------+------+
| tbl                     | num  |
+-------------------------+------+
| appObjectGroups         | 1141 |
| appObjectDependencies   | 6153 |
| appObjectUrls           | 1141 |
| appObjectValues         | 3584 |
| appObjects              | 6061 |
+-------------------------+------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**so how come that `table_rows` report something different than `count(*)`?**

and more important to me: which one is correct? :-)

Comment: assuming those are innodb tables, what's in information_schemal is only an estimate. the actual count is conditional upon WHO is running the query, and WHEN the query is executed. e.g. two users, one has 50 rows inserted in an uncommitted transaction, the other does a count, and will get only the "real" row count, not the real+50 virtual/uncommited count.

Comment: yes those are innodb tables. sounds reasonable. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html):

> For InnoDB tables, the row count is only a **rough estimate** used in SQL
>   optimization. (This is also true if the InnoDB table is partitioned.)